# mvn.bat not executing properly

Tags: maven

At the setup of maven in my machine 'mvn.bat' is not executing properly. Gives error "no goals have been specified for this build...".

JAVA_HOME is set fine.
Though there is no error for 'mvn --version'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that error is pretty self-explanatory:

```
No goals have been specified for this build.     
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format 
<plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources,
generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile,
process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, 
integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site,
post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean.
```

You have not specified any goals. You have to. Most probably you want `mvn install` or `mvn clean install`. I recommend reading up on Maven usage and examples.

Comment: But do plain running of mvn.bat also requires goals?

Comment: As you can see in the error there is no such thing as plain running it. It might be easier if instead in your question you described what is it you want to accomplish, since running mvn.bat does not seem to be what you're looking for.